# スマホ端末上で動画ファイルの容量圧縮を行いたい。

Tags: ios, android, unity2d, 動画

Unityで開発を行っております。
スマホ端末から1GB1時間30分相当の動画ファイルを300MB以下オーディオ無しの動画に容量圧縮を行いたいと考えております。
時間や電池消費は無視した場合、このようなことができるでしょうか。
またはアセットなどご存じでしょうか。

「FFmpeg Unity Bind」という有料アセットを見つけたのですが、すでにサポートが終了しているようでしたので、故意らの仕様は考えておりません。

Comment: Mobile-FFmpeg とかでいかが？ [UnityでMobile-FFmpegを使う - Qiita](https://qiita.com/tanho_fukasawa/items/671cf50fddfec13eb5e1)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
現在実装を進めているのですが、x-codeで

building for ios but the linked framework 'shine.framework' was built for Mac Catalyst

といったリンクエラーが出てしまい、ビルドが通らない状況です。
フレームワークは「mobile-ffmpeg-full-4.4-ios-xcframework.zip」を解凍したものを
「Assets\Plugins\iOS」に配置しております。
取得したフレームワークが間違っているのでしょうか？

Comment: フレームワークのリンクエラーの件は「mobile-ffmpeg-full-4.4.LTS-ios-framework.zip」を解凍したものに差し替えることで対応いたしました。
しかし、ビルド時に大量のUndefined symbolが発生しております。
これは何か足りていないのでしょうか